# The visualizer encountered an internal exception and must be closed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging

I use Visual Studio 2022. When I try to use the `IEnumerable` visualizer, I see this error

> The visualizer encountered an internal exception and must be closed

- I reset all Visual Studio settings, but problem is still here
- I have not used the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" option

[image]

[image]

Comment: same happened with me after updating VS2022 to 17.7.4

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. Open VS 2022, then go to [Tools] -> [Nuget Package Manager] -> [Package Manager Console].
Run
'Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json'
This will install the latest version which matches the version required by VS2022 in my case.

Comment: yes. this worked!

Answer (score 0):

If possible, please share a minimalize reproduce sample.

Please make sure the Just My Code is enabled:

[image]

and if this issue is caused by the new version of Visual Studio, you could download and install the older version Visual Studio via this:

[Release Dates and Build numbers of Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history#release-dates-and-build-numbers)

Comment: This option was active, I have tested in active and inactive mode, but the problem was not solved.
After installing Visual Studio 2022, I had to install 2019. When I noticed this problem, I assumed it had something to do with it, so I uninstalled Visual Studio 2019, but it didn't fix the problem.
I deleted version 17.7.4 and reinstalled it, but the problem is still there. Therefore, this problem probably appeared after the update and it is better to wait until the next version to fix it.

Comment: @FarzanehTalebi I am sorry, VS2022 old versions are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history#fixed-version-bootstrappers You can have a try of the old versions. :)